# Why does the class access variables from its metaclass when calling class __init__?

Tags: python, metaclass

```
r={'a':6} 
c = Myclass(**r) 
out: a
```

when I executed `Myclass(**r)`, this class called `fields` from `MyMeta`, not from `Myclass`. What happens in this process? Why isn't it using `fields` from `Myclass`?

```
class MyMeta(type) : 
    def __new__(mcs,name,bases,attr) : 
        fields = {} 
        fields['a'] = 2 
        fields['b'] = 4 
        fields['c'] = 44
        if '__init__' not in attr:
            def init(self,**kwargs): 
                self.api = kwargs.pop('api', None) 
                for k,v in kwargs.items(): 
                     if k in fields : 
                         print(v) 
            attr['__init__'] = init 
        return type.__new__(mcs,name,bases,attr)

class Myclass(metaclass = MyMeta ):
    fields = {'c': 5} 
    def get(self):
        print(4)
```

Comment: `if k in fields` clearly refers to the `fields` variable defined in the same function a few lines up. If you’re interested in the class attribute by the same name, you will have to explicitly access the class attribute. This wouldn’t work even if you defined `def __init__` directly on `Myclass`.

Comment: I know it is not an easy concept and therefore I think you need to read up a bit on how metaclasses work. Very short, the metaclass is responsible fr creating your class. Thus at create time, the metaclass is called and executes. Its return value is the class that is acutally created, i.e. `Myclass`. But while the metaclass, `MyMeta` is excuting, the `Myclass`object does not even exist, and thus cannot be accessed, inlcuding the `fields` dict that it (`Myclass`) contains.

Comment: @JohanL  Many thanks !   Actually I know a bit how the metaclasses create classes : Metaclass will call inside __new__ to create a class .   In my codes, when initiate Myclass, '__init__' from the metaclass Mymeta will be called.  why does this 'init' function find fields which is from Mymeta ? Could you recommend some good introduction material on this process ??

Comment: Why are you using a custom metaclass at all?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you need a metaclass here, *you probably don't*. But for the sake of the exercise, let's examine what it going on.

The scope of Python's function is defined like this

```
locals > closure > globals > builtins
```

Never will a function lookup in the namespace of the scope where it was called. Notice that in this case, even defining `MyClass.__init__` would not work since class methods must access their class namespace through attributes.

```
class SomeClass:
    foo = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo # works
        foo # raises NameError
```

In particular, this means your `init` method will find `fields` in the body of `MyMeta.__new__`, which is its closure.

Although, note that the namespace of a class is passed as fourth argument to the `MyMeta.__new__` method, here `attr`. So, you can find `Myclass.fields` at `attr['fields']` in `MyMeta.__new__`.

#### Example

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attr):
        fields = {'foo': 0}

        def init(self, **kwargs):
            print('kwargs:', kwargs)
            print('MyMeta.__new__.fields:', fields)
            print('attr["fields"]:', attr['fields'])

        attr['__init__'] = init
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, attr)


class Myclass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    fields = {'bar': 1}


r = {'baz': 2}
c = Myclass(**r)
```

#### Output

```
kwargs: {'baz': 2}
MyMeta.__new__.fields: {'foo': 0}
attr["fields"]: {'bar': 1}
```

Comment: If that answer was helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Cheers!